# Logo size in email confirmation is huge

Tags: cognito-forms

When the email confirmation is received, the logo is huge.

How do I reduce the size of the logo in the confirmation email?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a developer for Cognito. The best way to ensure your logo is the right size is to shrink it down in an image editor like Photoshop, Gimp, or Pixlr (a free web app: http://apps.pixlr.com/editor/).

We'll fix the confirmation emails so the dimensions of huge logos are constrained a little, but you'll still probably want to size it yourself. Not only will that give you more control but it should also shrink the file size for the folks downloading the email.